# Error Template Adorner on DataGridCheckBoxColumn Can't Be Overridden

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
   Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"/>
```

I'm trying to remove the red box from the cell. The errortemplate=null in this doesn't change anything.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCheckBoxColumn}" >
   <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
```

That too doesn't do anything. I've tried DataGridCell, DataGridRow, ContentTemplate, Checkbox styles. Nothing removes the ugly looking red box from the cell.

I snooped it and found that an adorner is being made automatically, unnamed and templated. It's attached to the checkbox.

The only way I've gotten around it is to change to a DataGridTemplateColumn and make a Checkbox directly in a data template. However, this is roundabout and undo's a lot of other style templates I've done. Is there any way to make the Template columns, like Checkbox, not display the red error validation border around it?

The key here is that I want error validation. I just dont want the adorner it makes.

Comment: Have you tried adding a CheckBox-Style as resource to your Column and set the ValidationErrorTemplate on the checkbox to null?

Comment: Yes. The same Style TargetType as the one mentioned with OP as DataGridCell, DataGridRow, ContentTemplate, and Checkbox. None have affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution might be styling the `ElementStyle` like this.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Invalid, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Header="Invalid" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Note**:

To get rid of the red exclamationmark on the left do this:

```
RowValidationErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
```

on your `DataGrid`.

Comment: So this works, but I sadly lose all my stylings for my check box columns even if I used BasedOn. I have a style for readonly datagridcheckboxcolumsn and a style for when isreadonly is false on the datagridcheckboxcolumn.

I thought I could be smart and do a datatrigger on the datagridcolumn to switch the style to a static resource depending if IsReadOnly is true or false, but it fails. I wish this was easier.